# Expanding vector while iterating through it

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function that iterates through a vector and calls another function to execute its contents in some manner. As a result of that execution new elements could be added to the vector. Function code is as follows:

```
void foo() {
    for (std::vector<Item*>::iterator it = item_list.begin(); it != item_list.end(); ++it ) {
        if (/*some condition*/) {
           bar(it);
        }
    }
}
```

While I was googling this problem I saw that iterator **might** get invalidated if resize happens, but the writer was not specific on why nor when or what is the proper way of handling this problem.

Comment: Your sample does not show a problem.

Comment: @DieterLücking: `item_list` could be a global that is modified by `bar`, but you're right that it's unclear if the sample has the problem, and it should be clarified.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Where are the new items being added? To the beginning/end/anywhere in the vector? If they're added before the current iterator are you OK with the `for` loop not iterating over them?

Comment: Function bar doesn't always add items to the item_list vector, but it can be one of the outcomes. If condition is an escape from the loop. So my question really is: if during iteration function bar adds another item to the list, will the iteration be able to continue iterating trough the vector or not.  The code i provided is just to show how the for loop in question is implemented i have not yet completed the bar function when i figured out this could be a problem.

Comment: @DieterLücking I'm guessing `bar` modifies `item_list` by adding elements, and if that causes reallocation, `it` will be invalidated, making the subsequent `++it` undefined behavior

Comment: @Praetorian Which means, the design is poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a vector is random access, you can store the distance temporarily and re-create the iterator afterwards:

```
void foo() {
    for (std::vector<Item*>::iterator it = item_list.begin(); it != item_list.end(); ++it ) {
        if (/*some condition*/) {
           const auto d = std::distance( item_list.begin(), it );
           bar(it);
           it = item_list.begin();
           std::advance( it, d );
        }
    }
}
```

The answer assumes that new elements are added *after* the current position, e.g., at the end. It also assumes that it is desirable that the new elements are also part of the iteration, i.e., they will also be checked against `some condition` and `bar` will be called if they do match.

Comment: Just use a list! (Of course, I assume that random access isn't needed)

Comment: @Throwback1986 That decision would have performance implications, you can't assume that OPs overall performance would benefit from that.

Comment: Sure, most (every?) design decision has implications.  OP *appears* to have issue with O(n) maintenance operations on a vector. Std::lists offer tidy and performant maintenance operations.

Comment: @Throwback1986 The calls to [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) and [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) in the above answer are O(1), not O(n). And you only need to do it if `some condition` matches.

Comment: See above references to "resize" and "realloc". O(1) is tough in those cases (other than the obvious case in which  n==1)

Comment: @Throwback1986 Even that is not necessarily true. It depends on where the new elements are inserted. The complexity is linear in distance to the end of the vector and, if you only append elements at the end, it is [amortized constant *O(1)*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Never underestimate `std::vector`!

Comment: I believe appending adds new constraints to the problem, as presented. If that's the case, append is clearly O(1) -  ignoring any bulk resize operations. However, I understand "append" to be a boundary case in this instance - one that is well hidden behind a resize or realloc that degenerates to O(n), or n/2 on average for the pedantic - which neatly falls back to O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting more items on that vector within a interaction, simply create another vector to store all the items and do the resizing while you iterate in this one, then you discard the current one and swap for that updated vector.

That's the standard way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), if inserting an element changes the capacity of the `vector`, all iterators are invalidated.

To work around this, add new items to a temporary `vector` and merge the two after you're done.